# Is there a way to create a static field in the model generated for swagger codegen?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I am trying to use swagger-codegen (the maven plugin) to generate my models. But I need one of my fields to be static. I was wondering if there's a property I could use in my yaml file to indicate that the field is static. Does anyone have an existing example I could look at?